# terraform state replace-provider doesn't update to new provider

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider

So I ran this:

```
terraform state replace-provider terraform-mars/credstash granular-oss/credstash
```

and this was the output

```
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  ~ Updating provider:
    - registry.terraform.io/terraform-mars/credstash
    + registry.terraform.io/granular-oss/credstash

Changing 1 resources:

  module.operations.data.credstash_secret.key_name

Do you want to make these changes?
Only 'yes' will be accepted to continue.

Enter a value: yes

Successfully replaced provider for 1 resources.
```

then I checked it with

```
terraform providers
```

```
Providers required by configuration:
.
├── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/archive] ~> 2.2.0
├── provider[registry.terraform.io/vancluever/acme] ~> 2.5.3
├── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws] ~> 4.13.0
├── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/dns] ~> 3.2.3
├── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/local] ~> 2.2.3
├── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/cloudinit] ~> 2.2.0
├── provider[registry.terraform.io/granular-oss/credstash] ~> 0.6.1
├── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/external] ~> 2.2.2
├── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/null] ~> 3.1.1
├── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/tls] ~> 3.4.0
├── module.account
│   ├── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws]
│   └── module.static
└── module.operations
    ├── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/local]
    ├── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws]
    ├── provider[registry.terraform.io/terraform-mars/credstash]
```

It still uses the old provider for some reason.
I don't understand why this happens.

I also ran `terraform init` but the provider still shows up there also.

When I run `terraform plan`, it gives me this error:

```
Error: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.
│   For verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors
│
│   with module.operations.data.credstash_secret.key_name,
│   on ../modules/stacks/operations/bastion.tf line 1, in data "credstash_secret" "bastion_pubkey":
│    1: data "credstash_secret" "key_name" {
```

Comment: Is the provider defined at the module level as well? If so, you have to replace it there as well.

Comment: yes, I missed that. Working now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The part of the `terraform providers` output included in the question is describing the provider requirements declared in the configuration. This includes both explicit [provider requirements](https://www.terraform.io/language/providers/requirements) and also some automatically-detected requirements that Terraform infers for backward compatibility for modules written for modules that were targeting Terraform v0.12 and earlier.

The `terraform state replace-provider` command instead replaces references to providers inside the current Terraform state. The Terraform state remembers which provider most recently managed each resource so that e.g. Terraform knows which provider to use to destroy the object if you subsequently remove it from the configuration.

When you use `terraform state replace-provider` you'll typically need to first update the configuration of each of your modules to refer to the new provider instead of the old and to make sure each of your resources is associated (either implicitly or explicitly) with the intended provider. You can then use `terraform state replace-provider` to force the state to change to match, and thereby avoid the need to install the old provider in `terraform init`.